# is calling glViewport in OpenGL programs on Android necessary?

Tags: android, opengl-es

In most of Android OpenGL examples I saw people calling glViewport in onSurfaceChanged. However, I just noticed that if I comment it out, my program still behaves the same. So it is necessary at all to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to call `glViewport` in the `onSurfaceChanged` handler when your gl view dimensions are modified. Usually it is when device is rotated and view's width and height are swapped.

In case when `width = height` or view is not rotated, the call to `glViewport` is unnecessary.

By default `Activity` will be recreated after rotation. To avoid this, you need to specify that your activity is [handling rotation itself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config). You need to add these config options in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="Activity"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation">
```

After you've done this, your activity will retain your OpenGL context.

Comment: Hm - but when the device is rotated the surface is - as far as I can see - destroyed and recreated.